# Problems with obtaining and saving 2D slices from a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I'm trying to save a 2D slice of a 3D array that I'm slicing with the following code:

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
from nibabel.testing import data_path
import os

vol1= np.load("teste01.npy")
zSlice= (vol1[1, :, :]).squeeze()
print (zSlice.shape)
np.save(zSlice, os.path.join("D:/Volumes convertidos LIDC/slice01.npy"))
```

I'm getting an error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ndarray

Is there any way to fix this? **I need 2D arrays in order to be able to insert my images into an automatic lung vessel segmentation model but I only have 3D images, is there any way to obtain all the slices from said 3D image instead of slicing it manually (like I'm trying to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just mixed up the parameters for [numpy.save](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). Use the filename as the first parameter and the data as the second:

```
np.save(os.path.join("D:/Volumes convertidos LIDC/slice01.npy"), zSlice)
```

Comment: Belive me or not, you saved my life with this. Thank you! Do you know if it's possible to obtain all the slices automatically?

Comment: Hehe, I'm glad I could help. I used Numpy only a few times so I don't know much about slices. But why not ask another question?

Comment: I will do that!